# Sending message with Facebook Api without webhook

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

there is a FB login on my website, i can see Facebook app scoped user id which login to my website via fb login. I need to notify them with Fb messenger, is there  need Webhook? can i send them message without waiting send message to my page.
When i used them app scoped user id, graph api return an error and it says "No matching user found". What is the problem?

Comment: you can only send messages to users after they sent your page a message or started using a bot. you can NOT send them a message just because they authorized your app on your website.

Comment: thank you, can i send a message after 1 hour or 1 day if they sent a message to my page. Or should i send a message at the time when they sent?

Comment: yes, of course. why not just try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910662/internal-server-error-while-setup-fb-webhook